# How to apply style to a row up till a specified cell in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to apply a border style to a row but not tp the entire row. I want to apply it till 33rd cell. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a style you want:

   ```
           HSSFCellStyle my_style = my_workbook.createCellStyle();    

         /* Draw a thin left border */
           my_style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);/* Add medium right border */
           my_style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);/* Add dashed top border */
           my_style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_DASHED); /* Add dotted bottom border */
           my_style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_DOTTED);
   ```
2. Create a row:

   ```
       /*Create a row */
       Row row = my_sheet.createRow(0);
   ```
3. Add cells to the row with your desired border style:

   ```
       /*Now add cells to the row*/
       Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
       cell.setCellValue("Add Border Example - 1 ");  
       /*Now add style to your cell
       cell.setCellStyle(my_style);
   ```
4. Repeat the process of creating cells for the row created earlier